# Type Mismatch Error while convert object in swift

Tags: swift

**How to convert `string` to `Int` while convert object in `city_id` ?**

---

> Error when received data from api and convert into object

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "city_id", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

---

```
class ObjUserInfo: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var firstName, lastName, email: String
    var cityID: Int
    var city, country: String
    var countryID: Int
    var countryFlag: String
    var phone, birthDate: String
    var gender: Int
    var genderText: String
    var profileImage, coverImage: String
    var profileInfo: String
    var accessInfo: AccessInfo
    var userFavouriteSports: [ObjSportsList]
    var languages: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case firstName = "first_name"
    case lastName = "last_name"
    case email
    case cityID = "city_id"
    case city, country
    case countryID = "country_id"
    case countryFlag = "country_flag"
    case phone
    case birthDate = "birth_date"
    case gender
    case genderText = "gender_text"
    case profileImage = "profile_image"
    case coverImage = "cover_image"
    case profileInfo = "profile_info"
    case accessInfo = "access_info"
    case userFavouriteSports = "user_favourite_sports"
    case languages
}

init(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, cityID: Int, city: String, country: String, countryID: Int, countryFlag: String, phone: String, birthDate: String, gender: Int, genderText: String, profileImage: String, coverImage: String, profileInfo: String, accessInfo: AccessInfo, userFavouriteSports: [ObjSportsList], languages: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.email = email
    self.cityID = cityID
    self.city = city
    self.country = country
    self.countryID = countryID
    self.countryFlag = countryFlag
    self.phone = phone
    self.birthDate = birthDate
    self.gender = gender
    self.genderText = genderText
    self.profileImage = profileImage
    self.coverImage = coverImage
    self.profileInfo = profileInfo
    self.accessInfo = accessInfo
    self.userFavouriteSports = userFavouriteSports
    self.languages = languages
}
}
```

---

**How to convert string to Int while convert object in `city_id` ?**

- Code for convert object

```
let decoderdec = JSONDecoder()
//decoderdec.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

// 2. Create Data from Response
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonResponse["data"] as Any)

let objUser = try decoderdec.decode(ObjUserInfo.self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: Implement your own `init(from decoder: Decoder)` (or declare property to be String)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thank you for comment, Have you any example?

Comment: The answer below is an example but skip the horrilble `!` after `try`. Note that you need to handle each property if you go this route so an easier solution is to declare the property as string in your struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Yes, you shouldn't force unwrap values in production code -- the previous code was simply for a demonstration purpose. Anyways, I editted the code regarding the comment by @Joakim Danielson above.

You should implement a custom `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` method.

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
  let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

  // Left hand side `id` is for the property, and `forKey: .id` is the case in 
  // your enum CodingKeys
  id = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
  ...
  // First try decoding from String, and covert it to Int.
  // If it wasn't String, try decoding from Int.
  if let rawCityID = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .cityID),
     let cityID = Int(rawCityID) {
    self.cityID = cityID
  } else {
    cityID = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .cityID)
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hey, Any way to check `cityID` is `string` or `Int` ?

Comment: I editted the code to handle optionals and fail more gracefully.